# why can't we digest cellulose

Tags: digestive-system

I have a very tricky question....all the veg and fruit

cells contain cell wall and it is made of cellulose when we eat how our body digest though we

don't have the enzymes to breakdown 1-4 beta glucose sugar?

Comment: We don't digest cellulose; it just passes through us unchanged.

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/59205/24354

Answer (score 1):

Humans, unlike cows for ex. don't have the necessary bacteria in their intestines that make the enzymes(cellulases) necessary to breakdown the 1-4 beta glucose bonds. So we cannot break down cellulose into its constituent glucose molecules as we do with starch. Therefore this is secreted as unbroken down chains of glucose called fiber.

Comment: tnx sir for your reply...but it didn't satisfy me i asked so how we can eat fruits and vegs they all got celloluse in thier cell wall

Comment: That's why I tried to explain that those parts of vegetables we can't digest are called fiber.

Comment: so then why in many biscuits and chocalate companies ads they say it fibers and etc if we can't digest it then why they promote it?